# Cannot add Windows target in prometheus.yml using hostname

Tags: raspberry-pi, prometheus

First, apologies. I'm assuming that I've missed something simple, but I just don't see it.

I want to add a Windows 7 desktop (hostname: DELL7010) to Prometheus using wmi_exporter. I also want to add it using its hostname rather than its IP address since I want the IP address to remain dynamic. The network is a simple 10.1.1.x home network with no internal DNS service.

I have installed wmi_exporter (v0.11.0) successfully and can browse to the localhost url (http://localhost:9182/metrics) successfully.

On my Prometheus server (A Raspberry Pi running Buster), I already have multiple other Linux servers being monitored using static IPs assigned in the prometheus.yml file. So I am comfortable that Prometheus is operating correctly.

In order to ensure that the Prometheus server could resolve the hostname of the Windows server I installed winbind and libnss-winbind and added 'wins mdns4' to the end of the 'hosts:' line in `/etc/nsswitch.conf`. After doing this I can successfully `ping DELL7010.local` or `ping DELL7010` from the Prometheus server. Additionally I can run `curl http://DELL7010:9182/metrics` or `curl http://DELL7010.local:9182/metrics` from the command line on the Prometheus server and have the metrics returned to the terminal.

However, when I add

```
- targets: ['DELL7010:9182']
```

or

```
- targets: ['DELL7010.local:9182']
```

to my prometheus.yml file I get an error in the Prometheus targets page that indicates that the server state is 'down' and the error returned is;

```
Get http://DELL7010.local:9182/metrics: dial tcp: lookup DELL7010.local on 10.1.1.1:53: no such host
```

This is in spite of the endpoint for the server appearing on the Prometheus targets as 'http://DELL7010.local:9182/metrics'.

The address that appears in the error is the local address of my ADSL modem, so I make the assumption that it is deciding that the hostname is not resolvable and is looking for assistance from the modem. But I'm not sure why or how to convince Prometheus that the hostname is where I want to send it. I've looked for alternative configuration options in `prometheus.yml` but can't find an option that would force the issue.

**EDIT**: I have discovered that the IP address reported in the error (10.1.1.1) is coming from `/etc/resolv.conf`. Which makes sense as a mechanism for Prometheus to resolve determine hostnames. However, it in the situation described above I'm not sure how to leverage it to solve the problem

**EDIT**: To mitigate this problem in the mean time I have assigned an IP reservation for the Windows machine on my router and am using an IP address in Prometheus.